# How can I highlight cells based on how close they are to a whole number?

Tags: excel

I want to highlight numbers closer to the next whole number a darker green and numbers father away from the next whole number a darker red.
For example, 1 = dark green, 1.1 = dark red, 1.3 = lighter red, 1.5 = white, 1.7 = light green, 1.9 = dark green, and 2 = dark green

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via *color scaling* with the setting *formula*.

As an example for A1:

```
GN: =IF(TRUNC($A$1)=$A$1,$A$1-1.1,TRUNC($A$1))
WH: =IF(TRUNC($A$1)=$A$1,$A$1-1,TRUNC($A$1)+0.5)
RD: =IF(TRUNC($A$1)=$A$1,$A$1,TRUNC($A$1)+1)
```

This way, it will work as you want it.

There are just two problems: references need to be absolute and you can't use it array-like (for range A1:A10 directly use $A$1:$A$10).

As the formula uses absolute references, you can not copy/paste it anywhere (it will always look for the original cell). This way you would need to enter it manually for every cell... but excel got a solution for this: VBA!

Simply select the cells you want the rules and run this code:

```
Sub format_me()

  Dim x As Range, y As String

  For Each x In Selection.Cells
    y = x.Address

    x.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    x.FormatConditions(x.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With x.FormatConditions(1)
      With .ColorScaleCriteria(1)
        .Type = 4
        .Value = "=IF(TRUNC(" & y & ")=" & y & "," & y & "-1.1,TRUNC(" & y & "))"
        .FormatColor.Color = 7039480
        .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
      End With

      With .ColorScaleCriteria(2)
        .Type = 4
        .Value = "=IF(TRUNC(" & y & ")=" & y & "," & y & "-1,TRUNC(" & y & ")+0.5)"
        .FormatColor.ThemeColor = 1
        .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
      End With

      With .ColorScaleCriteria(3)
        .Type = 4
        .Value = "=IF(TRUNC(" & y & ")=" & y & "," & y & ",TRUNC(" & y & ")+1)"
        .FormatColor.Color = 8109667
        .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
      End With
    End With

  Next

End Sub
```

Empty cells will have no color (still the rule is there and as soon as a number is in it, you will get the color without running the code a second time)

*Alternatively, you also could create 511 different rules (for all possible shadings over 3 colors) but I am to lazy to write a code for that solution right now* :P

If you have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: @TimWilliams as said: color scaling does not allow relative references in formulas... that said: you are wrong... sorry

Comment: Thank you for the through help! If I may ask, how do I make it so that Excel knows which cells I'm trying to select to follow the VBA code? (https://snag.gy/XGL9Fh.jpg) Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to format.

Comment: Simply highlight (select) the cells you want... (like you would to copy then)... and then run the code ;)